# jQuery to get another sites page content / div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to grab some tracking information from a website and tried to use `load` and `ajax` but I'm getting the following errors:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.tuffnells.co.uk/PODLookupResults.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGU…%24tbDestPostcode=AL15BY&ctl00%24maincontent%24btnDoPODLookup=Search+Again. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What I have tried:

```
<div id="tracking"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tracking").load( "http://www.tuffnells.co.uk/PODLookupResults.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATEGUID=7ca82b1d-b722-4cdc-b74a-b338d8577ffa&__VIEWSTATE=&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAevVXD1oYELeveMr0vHCmYPaomE%2FDwQD43eOdzEj3p%2Fm4U4pgxq6tlupSJfQZQBazFFj%2F1LmlGLyHFagz1yHZm8bjowVgAJ8C3e%2B2bVMPt91KjXCHjnAsonQDi2zFSuasUVzpitHiLDCDtiLHCjNCQG4CxrbV5VPFqBeOgs2X52AD%2FEb%2BYR%2BEJ68PaN2CiyKzE%3D&ctl00%24ctl16%24tbHeaderSearch=Search..&ctl00%24maincontent%24tbAccountRef=01484267&ctl00%24maincontent%24tbConsignmentRef=2837&ctl00%24maincontent%24tbDestPostcode=AL15BY&ctl00%24maincontent%24btnDoPODLookup=Search+Again #ctl00_maincontent_pnlPODRecords" );
  });
</script>
```

and

```
<div id="tracking"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var url = "http://www.tuffnells.co.uk/PODLookupResults.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATEGUID=7ca82b1d-b722-4cdc-b74a-b338d8577ffa&__VIEWSTATE=&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAevVXD1oYELeveMr0vHCmYPaomE%2FDwQD43eOdzEj3p%2Fm4U4pgxq6tlupSJfQZQBazFFj%2F1LmlGLyHFagz1yHZm8bjowVgAJ8C3e%2B2bVMPt91KjXCHjnAsonQDi2zFSuasUVzpitHiLDCDtiLHCjNCQG4CxrbV5VPFqBeOgs2X52AD%2FEb%2BYR%2BEJ68PaN2CiyKzE%3D&ctl00%24ctl16%24tbHeaderSearch=Search..&ctl00%24maincontent%24tbAccountRef=01484267&ctl00%24maincontent%24tbConsignmentRef=2837&ctl00%24maincontent%24tbDestPostcode=AL15BY&ctl00%24maincontent%24btnDoPODLookup=Search+Again";
      $.ajax({
        url:url,
          type:'GET',
          success: function(data){
            $('#tracking').html($(data).find('#ctl00_maincontent_pnlPODRecords').html());
          }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Anyone have any ideas? I need to get the tracking details into our tracking page as they don't provide a API.

Comment: you can not load any domain from your app unless site configured to allow cross domain requests. read here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: It seems obvious they don't want you to use their data on any random third party website. That's said, you could just google your message error to get alternative server side. But what would you think if someone else use your data/server bandwitch without your own approuvement? Think about it...

Comment: You could try scrapping the website from your backend and then load it using ajax to your frontend. Try http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Comment: Api here for a company that is wired into them - just pick them only and could be good to go - they won't thank you for scraping their site constantly - https://www.aftership.com/docs/api/4

Comment: Thanks guys ill check it out, i did look at aftership but gave an error but ill take another look.

Comment: Api is definitely a better idea as @DarrenSweeney suggests. Scraping websites time is hopefully long gone.

Comment: Yea i know, im waiting for tuffnells to call me back on the API but not sure if they have one but were see, for the time being until they do will have to scrap.

Answer (score 0):

Answers staring right at you!

```
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with Javascript, use PHP instead :

```
    $.ajax({url: 'loadRemoteFile.php', type: 'POST', data: {loadPage: url}, success: function(data){
doStuff();
}});
```

and your PHP file :

```
if (isset($_POST['loadPage'])){
    echo file_get_contents($_POST['loadPage']);
```

Comment: Its using Shopify, you think can be done in that with the liquid templates?

Comment: I am able to create a php file and place on one of our other servers but how to i pass the url i want to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

I found the [link](http://itgroove.net/mmman/2013/03/21/how-to-pull-content-via-jquery-from-another-web-site-cross-domain-and-do-it-in-sharepoint-too/) which may be helpful for you i think.

Thanks